# Is it possible to get into a highly ranked math PhD program in the US without doing an REU or having research experience?

Tags: graduate-admissions, united-states, research-undergraduate

It seems that most students at graduate math programs in the US have participated in an REU or some sort of program where they can do some sort of research or do something outside of taking undergraduate math courses. Is it necessary to do something "extra"?

Comment: I'd like to see a reference for your first statement. Or are you guessing?

Comment: See the answer for the US to this canonical question: https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/176908/75368